# Why was there so much hate for Boomer from the Colonials?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In "Deadlock" Boomer and Ellen Tigh arrive at the Galactica. Tyrol identifies Boomer and Adama has her thrown in the brig. Later on in "Someone to Watch Over Me" the rebel Cylons request Boomer be extradited to answer for her crimes (siding with Cavil and going against her line).

There seems to be quite a lot of anger against Boomer from the Colonials, however, it has already been established that she wasn't aware that she was a sleeper agent and that she was programmed to shoot Adama.

The only thing that the Colonials could be angry about could be their experience on New Caprica, but it was never shown that Boomer did anything particularly awful (or was it?). Caprica 6 seems to be more accepted by the fleet, yet she jointly led the Cylons to try to live together with humans.

Is the anger explained anywhere ? A Webisode perhaps ?

Comment: Just because she didn't know she was a Cylon doesn't change the fact that she's a Cylon and the humans hate Cylons; the Colonials considered Boomer a traitor

Comment: @KutuluMike  At this point Adama has granted an amnesty to the final five, has a truce with a rebel Cylons, Caprica 6 has been released and is free to roam, Gaius Baltar is free (although attempts have been made on his life). Caprica 6 was a soldier and knowingly attacked the colonials (unlike Boomer). Adama forgave Roslin and Starbuck (twice) and Lee and the fleet that jumped to Kobol; he's very forgiving, but not to Boomer. She just helped them by bringing Ellen back.

Comment: It has to be remembered that none of the surviving humans is "in their right mind"; they're all suffering from advanced, prolonged PTSD. Just like the Bucket herself, they're all starting to come apart at the seams.

Comment: @koan for Adama specifically, Boomer _shot him_, so you can imagine he's going to hold lingering dislike for her.

Comment: @koan Those official actions didn't mean people in general stopped hating them. As for Adama, with Boomer it's personal.